# usermod equivalent for Alpine Linux

Tags: user-accounts, user-groups, alpine-linux

I'm building a Docker container, and I need to add my user to a group. `usermod` is not available in Alpine Linux by default. Apparently, you can add `shadow` from `apk` to install `usermod`, but I would prefer to not install additional packages.

Is there an alternative way to add a user to a group, or an equivalent tool to `usermod` available in Alpine?

Comment: [Have you seen this](https://github.com/chrootLogin/docker-nextcloud/issues/3#issuecomment-251181545)? Basically adding environment variables for UID and GID when initializing.

Comment: Why not simply modify the /etc/group file directly?

Comment: @davidgo Some people don’t know you can just edit it like that but it’s a good solution. Would need to be scriptable via `sed` or something like that.

Comment: `shadow` (`apk --no-cache add shadow`) is a very viable alternative if you need to retain exact host uid/gid and have no chance to the default commands adduser and addgrup do not support the `--non-unique` (allow to create users with duplicate (non-unique) UID) flag. Only weights less than 10MiB for those concerned about space consumption.

Answer (score 28):

You should be able to use the built-in `addgroup` command to add the user to a given group:

```
$ addgroup --help
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: addgroup [-g GID] [-S] [USER] GROUP

Add a group or add a user to a group

        -g GID  Group id
        -S      Create a system group
```

So running `addgroup ${USER} ${GROUP}` should update `/etc/groups` without needing to edit the file directly.

Comment: addgroup: gid '0' in use